# How to define a space command to be invisible between two Chinese chars but visible between a Chinese char and an alphabet char?

Tags: languages, cjk, chinese, ctex

I would like to define a command which stands for a whitespace between a Chinese char and an alphabet char, such that

1. it produces a whitespace when placed between a Chinese (CJK) char and an alphabet char, whereas
2. it produces nothing when placed between two Chinese chars and
3. (if possible) it produces a whitespace when placed between two alphabet chars.

As far as I know, the `ctex` macro package could make normal whitespace behave like this, but it is only available when building with XeLaTeX.

Is it possible to define such a command which works with unicode TeX engines (e.g., XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX)?

Comment: Are you using pdfLaTeX to type Chinese chars? Also, I'm a little confused, since this command you demanded needs to be inserted in the text manually, why not just use a normal space?

Comment: @Jinwen Thanks for pointing out the vagueness. I revise the question and exclude non-unicode TeX engines.

Comment: @Jinwen I need to use it in `\crefname` of `cleveref`, because `\crefname{Figure}{图}{图}` make the whitespace in `见 \cref{fig}` visible. But the whitespace between `见 图` is ignored and invisible. Without such a command, I must always be very careful about whitespaces around `\cref`, `\ref`, `\eqref` etc.—this is very annoying.

Comment: I think you should remove the space in `见 \cref{fig}`, and if you prefer this space in `见 图`, you can add it here: `\crefname{Figure}{\ 图}`.

Comment: @Jinwen Yes, but this is very annoying. You see, when composing with English only, commands can be treated as English also. So it is mandatory and natural to insert space before and after `\ref` and derivatives. But when composing with Chinese and English, I need to pay attention to the command containing Chinese chars and if I changed it later the behavior and semantic meaning changes a lot—unintended whitespaces may show up.

Comment: Hints given by Qing Lee, the author of `xeCJK` (in Chinese): https://github.com/CTeX-org/ctex-kit/issues/491#issuecomment-611502652

Comment: @muzimuzhiZ Thanks. I found it is not easy to have a flexible solution. As for my scenario, I use `\unskip` inside `\crefname` to automatically remove redundant spaces before `图` and `表`. Then I can just treat `cref{...}` as english-only part, and the problem is swept under the carpet. ;-)